# $G=\langle S|R\rangle$ is finitely presented simple, then if $w\neq e$ in $G$, $\langle\langle w\cup R \rangle\rangle = F(S)$

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, simple-groups, group-presentation

I'm having some trouble seeing

> $G=\langle S|R\rangle$ is finitely presented and simple, then if the world in free group $F(S)$, $w\neq e$ in $G$, $\langle\langle w\cup R \rangle\rangle = F(S)$

Symbol $\langle \langle \cdot \rangle \rangle$ denotes normal closure of the set of relations.

Since $G$ is simple, $w\neq e$, we would have $\langle \langle w \rangle \rangle = G$ since only normal set containing $w$ is $G$ itself.
But why does this say that $\langle\langle w\cup R \rangle\rangle = F(S)$?

$G$ is only $F(S)/\langle\langle R \rangle\rangle$ so I don't see any easy connection here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $w\neq e$ in $G$, therefore, $w\not\in\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$ in $F(S)$.  Thus, $\langle\langle w\cup R\rangle\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $F(S)$ properly containing $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$.  It follows that its image under the canonical homomorphism $F(S)\to G$ is a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$.  Since $G$ is simple, it must be all of $G$, so $\langle\langle w\cup R\rangle\rangle = F(S)$.  This follows from the [Correspondence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_%28group_theory%29), which establishes a one-to-one correspondence between the normal subgroups of $G$ and the normal subgroups of $F(S)$ containing $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$.

Comment: It might sound stupid, but why is it not possible that $\langle \langle w \cup R\rangle \rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $F(S)$? Since canonical homomorphism is in fact surjective, that its image is whole of $G$ doesn't necessarily mean that it is $F(S)$, does it?

Comment: @user160738 I have edited the answer to try to make it clearer.  I agree this might not be obvious if you are not familiar with the result that I linked to.

Comment: Ahh, I see! I'm very much a newbie at algebra, so forgive me. Thanks for pointing that out